# object HTMLSelectElement accessing value through this keyword

Tags: javascript

The below code doesn't it print the value.

```
function go(x)
{
   alert(x.options.selectedIndex.value);
   //location=document.menu.student.options[document.menu.student.selectedIndex].value
}
```

this is the html code

```
<select name="student" onChange="go(this)">
    <option selected> Student </option>
    <option value="http://www.cnet.com">Attendence</option>
    <option value="http://www.abc.com">Exams</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`selectedIndex` is a number, it doesn't have a `value` property.

If you have a `select` element which just allows single-select (as yours does), the easiest way to get its value is the [`select` element's `value` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-59351919):

```
function go(x) {
    alert(x.value);
}
```

Double-check that it works on the browsers you want to support, but MaryAnne (see the comments) has checked on all current major browsers and I've checked IE6, IE7, and Firefox 3.6 (e.g., older browsers), and they all work. Since it's specified in DOM2 HTML (the link above)...

But re `selectedIndex`, you probably meant:

```
function go(x) {
    alert(x.options[x.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

I'd probably take it a bit further and be more defensive:

```
function go(x) {
    var option = x.options[x.selectedIndex];
    if (option) {
        alert(option.value);
    }
}
```

...or

```
function go(x) {
    var option = x.options[x.selectedIndex];
    var value = option && option.value;
    alert(value); // Alerts "undefined" if nothing is selected
}
```

...in case there is no selected option (in which case, `option` will be `undefined`), although with your *particular* markup and code, I'm not aware of a user agent where the `change` event would be fired without there being anything selected. At least, I don't think so — "I think" being the reason for being defensive. :-)

Comment: A shorter way, `alert(x.value);` [works in this scenario](http://jsfiddle.net/bTMyr/) and I tried it in all major browsers. Could there be a situation where this "shortcut" is a bad idea?

Comment: @MaryAnne: As long as you try it in your target browsers and it works, great. To my surprise, `HTMLSelectElement#value` [**is** defined in DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-59351919) and seems to work on IE7, so if you've tested it on major current browsers, that suggests quite broad support. Obviously only relevant for single-select `select` elements, but those are the vast majority. I'd post that as an answer if I were you. If you don't, I'll add it to the above, but really it's your answer.

Comment: I have seen both methods (through `x.options[x.selectedIndex]` and directly, `x.value`) but wasn't so sure `x.value` would be valid everywhere, and I didn't test things like IE 6 or Safari. It reassures me to see that the W3C defines `x.value`. Please add this approach to your answer if you will, I think it's better than fragmenting information in two places.

Comment: @MaryAnne: Done. I've tested IE6, IE7, and Firefox 3.6. They all work. So if you've tried recent ones... :-)

Comment: Even after trying all these browsers, I still don't feel 100% assured about the short method. Going through options selected index is the mainstream method, from what I've seen. Anyway, thanks for the update!

Comment: @MaryAnne Madam, I tested it in crome and ie8. it return undefined. but FF returns the value!

Comment: @AbelJojo I don't have IE 8, in my Chrome 19 the JSFiddle I posted works as expected. Better play it safe and use T.J.'s functions!

Comment: @AbelJojo: `HTMLSelectElement#value` works for me in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/KkYNW/

Comment: how to get the Inner Text like 'Student',Attendance,exams through javascript i tried above all it is giving values in the Value fileds in the alerts