# Rails fine-uploader select folder from selectbox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fine-uploader

I try to select folders from select box and send request from fine uploader as a params. But send null. My codes is below

```
    //haml codes
    - path = "#{Rails.root}/public/templates/custom/"
    - folders = Dir["#{path}*"]
    %select#selected_path.form-control{name: 'folder'}
      %option{disabled: "disabled", selected: "selected"} Select
      - folders.each do |folder|
        %option{value: "#{Rails.root + folder}"}
          - if File.directory? folder
            = folder
```

For js code

```
 $('#fine-uploader-gallery').fineUploader({
  template: 'qq-template-gallery',
  request: {
      endpoint: '/admin/files/upload',
      params: {
          authenticity_token: "<%= form_authenticity_token %>",
          // gecici path eklendi
          selected_path: $('#selected_path').change(function() {
            alert($('#selected_path option:selected').val());
            $('#selected_path option:selected').val()
           })

      }
  }
});
```

But above selected_path params give me error. Returning from js `"selected_path"=>"[object HTMLSelectElement]"` error, not path. How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to haml, onchange

```
%select#selected_path.form-control{name: 'folder', :onchange => "go()"}
```

For js also

```
 $('#fine-uploader-gallery').fineUploader({
 template: 'qq-template-gallery',
 request: {
  endpoint: '/admin/files/upload',
  params: {
      authenticity_token: "<%= form_authenticity_token %>",
      // gecici path eklendi
      selected_path: function go() {
              var x = document.getElementById('selected_path');
              alert(x.value);
              return x.value;
      }
      }

  }
});
```

solved problem. 
I referenced from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11171135/3239403 answer.